# Highlight a row of a table using the id in angular-js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`. I have a table which is like -

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="manageResumeTable">
    <thead class="text-center text-info text-capitalize">
        <th class="text-center col-xs-1">Sr.No.</th>
        <th class="text-center col-xs-4">Document</th>
        <th class="text-center col-xs-1">Score</th>
        <th class="text-center col-xs-1">QuickScore</th>
        <th class="text-center col-xs-5">Actions</th>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles">
        <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{ file.temporaryId }}</td>
        <td class="view-orphan uploadResumeTableCellOverFlow col-xs-4">
            {{ file.attributes.name }}
        </td>
        <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{file.totalScore}}</td>
        <td class="text-center col-xs-1">{{file.attributes.quickScore}}</td>
        <td class="text-center col-xs-5">
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Annotate Un-annotated Words" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="getOrphans($index)">
                    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Promote to Gold Standard" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="markAsGoldStd(file.attributes.name)">
                    <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Delete from Corpus" data-ng-click="deleteResume(file.attributes.name)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Move to Archive" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !file.attributes.isUploadedDocument" data-ng-click="moveToSolar(file.attributes.name)">
                    <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            <button class="btn btn-labeled  btn-info" title="Add to Tracker" ng-disabled="!file.attributes.isCommitted || !isjdDeleted || !jdSelected"
                    data-ng-click="moveToJobDescription(file.attributes.name)">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So, Now I have a id which is coming from a `back-end`. I want to highlight a row whose `id is 1`. `Temporary Id is the ID here`.

Table data is like -

Sr.No  Document  Score  QuickScore  Actions
1      abc        12      5          aa

Here, When the ID is `1` then I want to highlight the row. Can any one please give me any Idea about it ? Thanks for the help.

Comment: add ng-class whose id is one. example ng-class="{'highlighterClass' : file.id == 1}";. .In you case <tr  ng-class="{'highlighterClass' : file.id == 1}" ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles">

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ngClass` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add a CSS class to `<TR>`

```
<tr ng-repeat="file in processResumeFiles"  ng-class="{'highlighterClass' : file.temporaryId == 1}">
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual highlighting should be done via CSS. Therefore your angular is code should simply set the call on the row you want to highlight to something that the CSS code can understand and highlight for you